# LWJGL Vertex Index Buffer causes half of "Mesh" to load

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I'm following the 3D Game Development with LWJGL book from Antonio Bejarano. I have reached the point of being able to render a quad to the screen. After having implemented the vertex index buffer, only one triangle of the quad renders to the screen, so I think it is safe to assume the problem is with that code.

```
        // Vertex Index Buffer
        idxVboId = glGenBuffers();
        vertsIdxBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocInt(indices.length);
        vertsIdxBuffer.put(indices).flip();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,idxVboId);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertsIdxBuffer,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The code for the vertices buffer and the colour buffer works, as I have removed the references to the index buffer and the full quad appears. I have also changed the render method to account for the new type to be rendered:

```
    shaderProgram.bind();

        //bind to vao
        glBindVertexArray(mesh.getVaoId());
        //enable positions buffer
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        //enable colour buffer
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        //draw verts
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 
        mesh.getVertexCount(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);

        //restore state (?)
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        shaderProgram.unbind();
```

Any suggestions are appreciated as I have been staring at this for hours and can't really see where I've made the mistake.

EDIT: Quad Mesh Code

```
     renderer.init();

    float[] positions = new float[]{
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    };

    float[] colours = new float[]{0.5f,0f,0f,0f,0.5f,0f,0f,0f,0.5f,0f,0.5f,0.5f};

    int[] indices = new int[]{
            0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2,
    };

    mesh = new BMesh(positions,colours,indices);
```

2ND Edit
Before and after positions array change

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwwpq.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAcoM.png)

Comment: Could be because of *backface-culling*? Do you have `GL_CULL_FACE` enabled, and which convention have you set it too? (see https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling). Also, show where and how you declared the quad mesh data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, im going to look in to the culling now, I have added  the code that forms the quad mesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the quad mesh initialization code, it seems the error is due to vertices `3` and `2` on the second quad being the same vertex, i.e. both are at `(0.5, 0.5, 0.0)`. Perhaps you mistakenly copied the 4th and 5th vertices in your array?

i.e. perhaps you meant to have

```
float[] positions = new float[]{
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
};
```

EDIT: Your indices seem to be wrong. Change them to `{ 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2 }`

Comment: I've attached two photos to show you what the alteration you proposed has achieved. There does now appear to be two separate triangles but they no longer line up, I think this could be to do with the values in the index buffer not lining up with the new positions array however.

Comment: @LiamDevlin yes because your indices are wrong. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, that's solved the issue. Moral of the story: check your co-ordinates :D

Comment: @LiamDevlin indeed yes, they can be a pain, even for something as simple as a quad / cube